# random number generator for special characters

Tags: java

I am trying to generate random number with special characters

what i do for simple integers is

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt();
```

what can i do to get some thing like this in my random numbers

```
String salt = "Random$SaltValue#WithSpecialCharacters12@$@4&#%^$*";
```

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try the following:

- Init your special characters set.
- Create a StringBuilder to contain your desired string.
- Get random character and append to StringBuilder object.

The code:

```
final String alphabet = "<Your special characters>";
final int N = alphabet.length();
Random rd = new Random();
int iLength = <length you want>;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(iLength);
for (int i = 0; i < iLength; i++) {
    sb.append(alphabet.charAt(rd.nextInt(N)));
}
```

Comment: A `StringBuilder` or a fixed length character array would make this more efficient.

Comment: @Duncan Jones You're right, thank for your advice !

Answer (score 7):

If you're happy to use third-party libraries, you may find the [`RandomStringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) class from Apache Commons Lang helpful.

You can specify the allowed set of characters (or use all available characters).

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {

  static Random r = new Random();

  static char[] choices = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" +
      "01234567890" +
      "$#_").toCharArray();

  public static String getSalt(int len) {
    StringBuilder salt = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (int i = 0; i<len; ++i)
      salt.append(choices[r.nextInt(choices.length)]);
    return salt.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[]_) {
    System.out.println(getSalt(32));
  }
}
```

Example output: `vdq5L6bANFIQH_MUyKyZxLcOkJeB3uJ1`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_characters special characters then try this

```
char c = (char) (randomGenerator.nextInt(0xB4 - 21 + 1) + 21);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String alphabet = "here specify all the characters you want";
    final int N = alphabet.length();

    Random r = new Random();
    String finalStr= "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
       finalStr+=alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N));
    }
```